# How to select same column of values with different date criterias and display as column1 and column2 in the same query

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

**For Example:** I have a table called Trans. There are three columns: `Date`, `Customer`, `Sales`:

```
Date       Customer      Sales
01/05/14     1           1000
02/05/14     2           5000
03/05/14     3           2500   
10/05/14     4           10000
01/12/13     1           25000 
02/12/13     2           500
06/12/13     3           1000 
31/12/13     4           3000
```

I would like to display Customer sales by date as:

```
Customer     Sales_2013     Sale_2014
  1            25000          1000
  2            500            5000
  3            1000           2500
  4            3000           10000
```

I have tried my level best and still trying :-(
any assistance would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks in anticipation.

Comment: Learn more about `pivot`.

Comment: What RDMS are you using?`SQL Server`, `Oracle` etc...

Comment: Sorry, I am using SQL Server 2008 R2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For `SQL Server` something like the below will work, the approach should work for any `TSQL`, may just need to alter the `CASE WHEN` for different `RDMS`. Note that you will need to change your field name `Date` to something else or you will inevitably run into problems.

```
SELECT Customer,
   sum(CASE WHEN datepart(year, Date) = 2013 THEN Sales ELSE 0 END) 
            As Sales_2013,
   sum(CASE WHEN datepart(year, Date) = 2014 THEN Sales ELSE 0 END) 
            As Sales_2014
FROM Trans
GROUP BY Customer
```

**EDIT**

And because you learn something new every day here would be the `PIVOT` approach, which I know works in `SQL Server 2005`, don't know about anything else:

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
    SELECT datepart(year,Date) As SlsYear,Customer,Sales
    FROM Trans
) As Source
PIVOT
(
    sum(Sales)
    FOR SlsYear IN ([2013],[2014])
) As Pvt
```

Forgive me if this is not quite correct, just learnt about `PIVOT` now...

**EDIT for Separate Tables as per Comment**

You should be able to do this by simply using a `UNION ALL` query.

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
    SELECT datepart(year,Date) As SlsYear,Customer,Sales
    FROM tbl2013Sales
    UNION ALL
    SELECT datepart(year,Date) As SlsYear,Customer,Sales
    FROM tbl2014Sales
) As Source
PIVOT
(
    sum(Sales)
    FOR SlsYear IN ([2013],[2014])
) As Pvt
```

Comment: @DAN, glad you are happy with the answer, please feel free to mark as answered (click the tick icon top left of my answer).

Comment: Hi Simon, the above query works fine when the 2013 sales table and the 2014 sales table are the same. What if the tables are different. TableA - 2013 sales and TableB - 2014 sales... any idea?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are using Sql Server, you can use following query

```
select a.id,
(select sum(sales) from salesData where datepart(year,Date)=2013 and id=a.id) as sales_2013,
(select sum(sales) from salesData where datepart(year,Date)=2014 and id=a.id) as sales_2014
from salesData as a
group by a.id
```

Sql fiddle
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/18d98/3/0

Answer (score 0):

```
create table #t(Date1 date,Customer int,Sales int)
insert into #t (Date1,Customer,Sales) values('01/05/14',1,1000),('02/05/14',2,5000),('03/05/14',3,2500),('10/05/14',4,10000),('01/12/13',1,25000),('02/12/13',2,500),('06/12/13',3,1000),('1/12/13',4,3000)


SELECT *
FROM
(
    SELECT datepart(year,date1) as Sales_year,Customer,Sales
    FROM #t
) As Source
PIVOT
(
    min(Sales)
    FOR Sales_year IN ([2013],[2014])
)piv;
```